# Passing an object to class constructor in runtime using structuremap

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, structuremap, constructor-injection

I have following class in my project:

```
public partial class MyForm : BaseForm, IMyInterface
{
    public MyForm(MyDto dto)
    {
        _dto = dto;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and use following code to register in structuremap:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.For<IMyInterface>()
            .Use<MyForm>()
            .Ctor<MyDto>("MyDto"));
```

When I want to use the class, I used following code:

```
var dto = new MyDto(){
            Id = 43,
            From = DateTime.Now(),
            To = DateTime.Now().AddDays(1)};

IMyInterface frm = ObjectFactory.Container.With("MyDto")
                   .EqualTo(dto).GetInstance<IMyInterface>();
```

But the passed `dto` value to the `frm` isn't same as I passed(`Id = 43`, ....), it is the default value of `MyDto` class(`Id = 0`, ...).
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following code to solve the problem:

```
IMyInterface frm = ObjectFactory.Container
                   .With<MyDto>(dto)
                   .GetInstance<IMyInterface>();
```